# Always response 401 (Unauthorized) for my Laravel Passport generated OAuth 2 token

Tags: laravel, rest, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401, laravel-passport

I am using:

- Postman/Insomnia for REST checking
- Laravel 5.6 with Laravel Passport
- Vagrant (Apache 2, PHP 7.2)

Made all checklist described on Laravel Docs for Laravel Passport and after certain steps I receive HTTP 401 for my valid OAuth access token.

1. Requested by /oauth/token/ the new access token with client_id and client_secret.
2. Used received access token to authorize my simple Laravel REST test controller with included Oauth api middleware.
3. The end is one: 401 unauthorized :(

So, here is some of my configurations:

**Apache**
[image]

**api route**
[image]

**Kernel.php**
[image]

**PassportServiceProvider.php**
[image]

**AuthServiceProvider.php**[image]

Comment: Why are you sharing screen shot? You can just add the code with your answer.

Comment: @MASh sorry, I though that screenshot is more pretty visual for understanding then the code snippet.

Comment: Then you are in wrong universe.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue too:

The difference between your codes and mine:
In the `routes/api.php`, i used only `auth:api`.
I didn't create `PassportServiceProvider.php` in the app folder.
In the `Kernel.php` mine is `client` not `client_credentials`.

I used `client_credentials` as `grant_type` in the POST request call.
In the result I always got 401.

Until I created a user using Password Grant Client:

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

And changed `client_credentials` to `password` in the POST request call:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

$access_token = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
```

Put the access token returned in the Bearer of the headers, and it works. 
And also you can get the current user using `$request->user();`

If you are using `client_credentials` as `grant_type`, it's going through the client middleware, so in the middleware `auth:api` needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Apache does not, by default, pass authorization headers to PHP. You need to edit your Apache site configuration to add a line to Deskpro's  directive. Note that this configuration must be added directly to Apache's configuration (e.g., adding it to htaccess will not work

```
<VirtualHost>
# ...
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
# ...
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an excellent answer and has helped me. Everything worked on the live server and it didn't work on my local system. Therefore it could only have been due to the development environment. This should be included in the Laravel documentation.

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication #A Note On FastCGI